# Calling up a loop value

Tags: java, database, for-loop, jodatime

I already have a .txt file that holds the months, dates, and the year of some bdays that I was able to find the differences between them(assume there are five that need to be sorted). I made a for loop that would find the differences between the dates, but I can't seem to figure out how to count a turn in a for loop (counting the difference of what dayCount was five times).

Here is the Bday.txt file that holds the dates.

```
    1 01 2011      John Pickard
    5 16 1968      Dad Apostol
    2 12 2003      Pax Johnson
    6 12 2009      Tired Joe
    12 1 2002      Joshua Ike
```

If we assume today is 8/26/2017, the totals between the dates (using jodatime) is

```
 //this is sorted, and the CORRECT
 [-237, -195, -102, -75, 97]
 //it goes as Pickard, Johnson, Apostol, Joe, Ike
 //what the wrong output is
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 //me attempting to put dayCount = 1 inside a for loop.
```

Here is my code:

```
 import chn.util.*;
 import java.util.Arrays;

 import org.joda.time.DateTime;
 import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
 import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
 import org.joda.time.Days;
 class starter{
     /*
    Trying to implement changes from mark 2.5 into mark 3
    */
    public static void main(String args[]){

    //to orginize what todays date is.
    EasyReader todaysmon;
    EasyReader todayday;
    EasyReader todayyear;

    //month-day-year

    //current
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;

    //the bday time month thing
    int bmonth;
    int bday;
    int byear;

    //set x = 0; x<numoflines; x++

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("What is the month right now? ");
    todaysmon = new EasyReader();
    month = todaysmon.readInt();
    System.out.print("What is today day? ");
    todayday = new EasyReader();
    day = todayday.readInt();
    System.out.print("What is the year today? ");
    todayyear = new EasyReader();
    year = todayyear.readInt();

    EasyReader database;
    database = new EasyReader("Bday.txt");

    //x = to how many lines are in the .TXT file.
    for (int x=0; x<5; x++){

    String[] myStrings = {database.readWord(),database.readWord(),database.readWord(),database.readWord(),database.readWord()};

    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myStrings));

        //this should do it with every value

        //this is a test if the thing is intilizing correctly.

        // for(int g = 0; g < myStrings.length; g++){
            // if(g == 0){
                //arrays go like this [0,1,2]
            // System.out.println("This is the month value: "+ myStrings[0]);
            // }
        // }

        //this will determine how maby days are the closest.

            for(int diffinday = 0; diffinday < myStrings.length; diffinday++){

            //making another copy 

            bmonth = Integer.parseInt(myStrings[0]);
            bday = Integer.parseInt(myStrings[1]);
            byear = Integer.parseInt(myStrings[2]);
            LocalDate start = new LocalDate(year,month,day);
            LocalDate end = new LocalDate(year,bmonth,bday);
            int dayCount = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
            System.out.println(dayCount);

                if(dayCount < 0){
                System.out.println("This value is null!");              
                }
                else{
                /*for now, we can only identify pos ints. we need to make an array that will 
                find the closest date, W/O IT BEING NEGATIVE*/
                System.out.println("The closest birthday is "+myStrings[4]);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: FYI, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class DatesDiff {
    private static String[] bdayDates = {"1 01 2011","5 16 1968","2 12 2003","6 12 2009","12 1 2002"};
    static int [] myArray = new int [bdayDates.length];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int diffinday = 0; diffinday < bdayDates.length; diffinday++){
            String bday = bdayDates[diffinday];
            int bmonth = Integer.parseInt(bday.split(" ")[0]);
            int birthday = Integer.parseInt(bday.split(" ")[1]);

            LocalDate start = new LocalDate(LocalDate.now().getYear(),bmonth,birthday);
            LocalDate end = LocalDate.now();
            int dayCount = Days.daysBetween(end, start).getDays();
            System.out.println(dayCount);
            myArray[diffinday] = dayCount;
            Arrays.sort(myArray);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));

            if(dayCount < 0){
            System.out.println("This value is null!");              
            }
            else{
            System.out.println("The closest birthday is "+bday);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, because I need the dates in a seperate .txt file. Good answer though

Comment: Once loop is finished hope you can copy dates in separate .txt file.

Comment: I need to get the dates from the separate file, and  be able to compute the difference w/o it being in the temp.java file using EasyReader. Eventually, the idea is that when I get 500+ dates, I can easily modify the code by making the for loop equal 500+. I can't copy 500 dates into the array though. That wouldn't be an effective way of doing the problem. Thanks for the answer though.